# regex javascript find all nam not following "Mrs"

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to find all name in double quoutes that not follow `Mrs`. Example:

```
Mr "Green" met Mrs "Smith" yesterday. Mrs "Smith" also met Mr "Brown" and "Peter".
```

The exact result will be: `Green, Brown, Peter`

The pattern:

```
/(?!^Mrs )"(?:""|[^"])*"/g
```

I used doesnt work. What is regex pattern to solve this in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
/\b(?!Mrs)\w+\s+"([^"]+)"/gi
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mZ7dY8/1)

**Code:**

```
var re = /\b(?!Mrs)\w+\s+"([^"]+)"/gi; 
var str = 'Mr "Green" met Mrs "Smith" yesterday. Mrs "Smith" also met Mr "Brown" and "Peter"s';
var m; 
var result = []
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex)
        re.lastIndex++;
    result.push(m[1]);
}

console.log(result);
// [Green, Brown, Peter]
```

Comment: Thank for your reply. It  captures word "and" in Mr "Brown" and "Peter". I also need double quotes included.

Comment: To include double quotes also use `var re = /\b(?!Mrs)\w+\s+("[^"]+")/gi;` and no it doesn't capture `and` in `m[1]`. Look at the shown code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this RegEx:

```
\b(?!Mrs)\w+\s+"(.*?)"
```

## [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mJ1nQ6/1)

Use it as:

```
var str = 'Mr "Green" met Mrs "Smith" yesterday. Mrs "Smith" also met Mr "Brown" and "Peter".', m, result = [], re = /\b(?!Mrs)\w+\s"(.*?)"/gi;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    m.index === re.lastIndex && re.lastIndex++;
    result.push(m[1]);
}

// Result is: ["Green", "Brown", "Peter"]
```